# The program 'python' received an X Window System error

Tags: python, user-interface

I've been creating a GUI interface for a little program to store books in a database.
Generally everything is ok but when I click on the "add buttom", after the action has been executed, the program closes and I can read on the terminal:

```
The program 'python' received an X Window System error.

This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)'.
(Details: serial 4916 error_code 3 request_code 15 minor_code 0)
(Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
```

I don't really understand what kind of error is this. I correctly use Tkinter libraries to create GUI (windows, buttons, forms, tables...)
Thanks to all

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?